# Zebra_form, get text inputs on the same line?

Tags: php, oop

I'm using Zebra_form to create my forms (first time I use it).

I would like to to have 3 text inputs on the same line :

Street Number Box

With this Code :

```
$form_investisseur = new Zebra_Form('form_investisseur');
$form_investisseur->language("francais");

$form_investisseur->add('label','label_rue', 'rue', 'Rue');
    $num_gsm = $form_investisseur->add('text', 'rue', null, array(
                                    'maxlength' => 80
                                ));
    $form_investisseur->add('label','label_numero', 'numero', 'N°');
    $num_gsm = $form_investisseur->add('text', 'numero', null, array(
                                    'maxlength' => 10
                                ));

    $form_investisseur->add('label','label_boite', 'boite', 'Boîte');
    $num_gsm = $form_investisseur->add('text', 'boite', null, array(
                                    'maxlength' => 10
                                ));
```

all inputs are under each other.

Do you think's possible to get them on the same line ?